# Use parent component to re-render child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, setstate

I'm creating a simple app and I'm having trouble re-rendering a child component. When setState is called in the parent component (App), the props passed down to the child component (CardContainer) don't cause it to re-render. I know I need to somehow use a function in App to call setState in CardContainer, but I'm stumped about how to do that. The state in App definitely changes (it shows up in console.logs), but **I need CardContainer to re-render the array it maps over once the App state is changed**. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is the App code (parent component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import AddButton from './AddButton';
import CardContainer from './CardContainer';
import style from '../style/App.css';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [{id: 1, title: 'first', text: 'Random stuff that is on the paage.'},
        {id: 2, title: 'second', text: 'More text goes here'},
        {id: 3, title: 'third', text: 'to doooo'}],
      cardSelected: false,
      selectedCard: []
    };
    this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this);
    this.deleteCard = this.deleteCard.bind(this);
    this.openSelectedCard = this.openSelectedCard.bind(this);
    this.closeSelectedCard = this.closeSelectedCard.bind(this);
    this.editExistingCard = this.editExistingCard.bind(this);
  }

  openSelectedCard(card) {
    this.setState({
      cardSelected: true,
      selectedCard: card
    })
  }

  closeSelectedCard() {
    this.setState({
      cardSelected: false
    })
  }

  addCard() {
    let newId = this.state.cards.length + 2;
    this.openSelectedCard({id: newId, title: 'Untitled', text: 'Just start typing here.'});
    // this.state.cards.push('New Post It');
    // this.setState({
    //   cards: this.state.cards
    // })
  }

  editExistingCard(cardToEdit) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cards.length; i++) {
      if(this.state.cards[i].id === cardToEdit.id) {
        this.state.cards.splice(i, 1);
        this.state.cards.splice(i, 0, cardToEdit);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards
    }, () => {this.closeSelectedCard()})
  }

  deleteCard(index) {
    console.log(this.state.cards[index])
    this.state.cards.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.appContainer}>
          <Header addCard={this.addCard}/>
          <CardContainer openSelectedCard={this.openSelectedCard} closeSelectedCard={this.closeSelectedCard} cards={this.state.cards} deleteCard={this.deleteCard} selectedCard={this.state.selectedCard} cardSelected={this.state.cardSelected} editExistingCard={this.editExistingCard}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the CardContainer code (child component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import SelectedCard from './SelectedCard';
import style from '../style/CardContainer.css';



class CardContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selecedCard: [],
      cards: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      cards: this.props.cards
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.cardContainer}>
          {this.state.cards.map((card, index) => (
            <Card card={card} key={card.id} index={index} title={card.title} text={card.text} openSelectedCard={() => this.props.openSelectedCard(card)} deleteCard={this.props.deleteCard}/>
          ))}
          {this.props.cardSelected &&
            <div className={style.selectedCardComponentContainer}>
              <SelectedCard card={this.props.selectedCard} closeSelectedCard={this.props.closeSelectedCard} editExistingCard={this.props.editExistingCard}/>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cards` from state in child component. user `this.props.cards` instead whcih will re-render your component whenever props will change. If still it does not work, use `component.forceUpdate()`

```js
class CardContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.cardContainer}>
          {this.props.cards.map((card, index) => (
            <Card card={card} key={card.id} index={index} title={card.title} text={card.text} openSelectedCard={() => this.props.openSelectedCard(card)} deleteCard={this.props.deleteCard}/>
          ))}
          {this.props.cardSelected &&
            <div className={style.selectedCardComponentContainer}>
              <SelectedCard card={this.props.selectedCard} closeSelectedCard={this.props.closeSelectedCard} editExistingCard={this.props.editExistingCard}/>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Zohaib! I actually tried that already and it doesn't work either. Maybe it's an asynchronous issue?

Comment: You should never use component.forceUpdate() because if you are using it, it means you have something wrong on your code that will possibly cause bugs on the future

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setState in `componentWillMount` this way the component won't re-render because you're calling a method inside a component that is not even  render yet. You should setState always on `componentDidMount` that's on the React Docs...

Hope helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Manuel! Unfortunately, I already tried that as well and it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried using componentDidReceiveProps() lifecycle method?

Comment: Yes, I tried that before I posted as well. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the `CardContainer` lifecycle.
The `cards` variable that is in the component state is only being set after the component will be mounted for the first time. You need to set it also whenever the component props are updated.

The fix:
You need to add something like this inside you `CardContainer` component:

```html
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    cards: nextProps.cards
  });
}
```

Edit:
Another fix would be to just use the cards you already have in the component `CardContainer` props.

Answer (score 0):

The child is not re-rendering because componentWillMount (which is deprecated so stop using it) and componentDidMount only fires on initial launch. Also I see that you've declared an empty array in the CardContainer component even though you're bringing in props as the constructor's parameters. Also, the SelectedCard component is receiving props.selectedCard. It looks like your cards array in state isn't used at all.

I hope you don't mind that I didn't hand you answer, but I think you should look at these points a little and re-evaluate your code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! I figured out that I actually need to call setState in the CardContainer's child, the Card component. The card was the actual component I wanted re-rendered, so I should have thought to make sure it was getting a setState as well. I thought updating the array that was populating the Cards would be enough.